# Facebook SDK - Get eMaiil

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Using the PHP SDK. I can log in and the app goes through the authentication ok (despite FB's greatest efforts to stop me!). The email displays courtesy of `<?php print_r($user_profile); ?>`

However, the array at the top of the example page always shows

```
[id] => 2
[oauth_uid] => 5
[oauth_provider] => facebook
[username] => 5
```

When I try to output the email, it again shows a value of **5**. How do I grab the email address? Why is it displaying **5**?

Comment: please post the code generating this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
<?php
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
print_r( $user_profile );
```

If you are asking for the `email` permission, the full email address will be visible.

Comment: Thanks! The script pointed to using $user['id'] rather than $user_profile['id']